# Quadrics into Grassmannian as zero locus of a section

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, vector-bundles, grassmannians, projective-varieties

Let $V$ be a $\mathbb C$-vector space of dimension $n+2$ with a symmetric bilinear non-degenerate map $q: V \times V \to \mathbb C$. We define
$$
G(k+1,V):=\{\mathbb PW \subset \mathbb PV : \dim W=k+1\},
$$
$$
OG(k+1,V):=\{\mathbb PW \subset \mathbb PV: \dim W=k+1 \text{ and }W \text{ is }q-\text{isotropic}\}.
$$
Then we need $V' \subset V$ a vector space of dimension $n$ that inherits a symmetric bilinear map given by the restriction $q|_{V'}$.
In the same way we define
$$
OG(k,V'):=\{\mathbb PW \subset \mathbb PV': \dim W=k \text{ and }W \text{ is }q|_{V'}-\text{isotropic}\}.
$$
I know that I have the following inclusions:
$$
OG(k,V') \hookrightarrow OG(k+1,V) \hookrightarrow G(k+1,V)
$$
and I want to study the normal bundle $\mathcal N_{OG(k,V')|OG(k+1,V)}$ via the sequence
$$
0 \to \mathcal N_{OG(k,V')|OG(k+1,V)} \to \mathcal N_{OG(k,V')|G(k+1,V)} \to \mathcal N_{OG(k+1,V)|G(k+1,V)}|_{OG(k,V')} \to 0.
$$
I know that the last normal bundle is given by $S^2 \mathcal S^\vee$ where $\mathcal S$ is the pullback of the tautological bundle over $G(k+1,V)$. My idea is to study $OG(k,V')$ as the zero locus of a section of a vector bundle over $G(k+1,V)$ in order to obtain the normal bundle in the middle of the sequence:
$$
Z(s)=OG(k,V') \hookrightarrow G(k,V) \to \mathcal F.
$$

I really cannot understand what $\mathcal F$ should be, even in the baby-case for $k=1$, where we have $OG(k,V')=Q^{n-1}$ is a quadric hypersurface. In this case I expect that $\mathcal F \to G(2,V)$ is a vector bundle of rank $n+2$, but what is the vector bundle?

Summing up:

- Is there a reference where this technique of viewing subvarieties as zero locus of sections is written in details? Surfing on various references I cannot find one that has a self-contained treatment.
- How one can attack the baby-case for $k=1$? I expect to can solve the general case once I have understood the first one.

Comment: A naive approach that might give you some insights (if you don't know this already). You can obtain $G(k, n+1)$ as zero locus of the bundle $\mathcal{Q}$ (the quotient) inside $G(k+1, n+2)$. The restriction of the tautological of ($\mathcal{S}$ in your notation) of $G(k+1,n+2)$ to the zero locus splits as the sum of the tautological $\mathcal{S}'$ to $G(k,n+1)$ and a copy of the trivial line bundle. You can then take the zero locus of $(\mathcal{S}')^\vee \oplus Sym^2 (\mathcal{S}')^\vee$ to get $OG(k,n)$.

Comment: By the way, in your last line I don't understand why you ask for a bundle of rank 2n+3 (unless I am misunderstanding the notation). In that specific case the quadric has dimension $n-2$, and the ambient Grassmannian $2n$, so the rank would be $n+2$.

Comment: @Enrico: First of all, you right, the rank is $n+2$. Thanks for pointing out!

I really cannot understand the first comment, because I miss the theory (that's why the first question of a good reference). Everything seems magic for me

Comment: @Enrico: If I understand correctly, you use the fact that
$$
OG(k,n) \hookrightarrow G(k,n+1) \hookrightarrow G(k+1,n+2),
$$
then you first see $G(k,n+1)$ as the zero locus of the quotient bundle on $G(k+1,n+2)$ and $OG(k,n)$ as the zero locus of $(\mathcal S')^\vee \oplus S^2 (\mathcal S')^\vee$ on $G(k,n+1)$, am I right? Then I think I have to compose the two things...

Comment: yes, exactly. Or you can pullback $\mathcal{S}'$ to $G(k+1, n+2)$ and do everything over there.
(about references: "Cohomology of Vector Bundles and Syzygies" by Weyman is an excellent source on the topic!)

Comment: There are a few things I missed.
First, $\mathcal S'$ is the tautological bundle over $G(k,n+1)$, how can I pullback to $G(k+1,n+2)$? Maybe push-forward? Second, I know that $OG(k,n)$ is the zero locus of $S^2 \mathcal S^\vee \to G(k,n)$, but you used $G(k,n+1)$. Sorry, maybe it's trivial but I can't get it